# React Native make running services

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[image]

This apps closed but services are running. How can i do this on react-native?
I would like to make services that listen my app notification.

Comment: headless js tasks, or a service class written in java

Comment: I try to make headless js tasks but , if app closed , task not working

Comment: you might want to check if your phone, if it has restricted the app to work in background

Comment: Have you had a look at this: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/headless-js-android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `react-native-firebase` package for this specific purpose.

Way 1 - **Data only notification**

Check out the data only notification section documentation [here](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/messaging/receiving-messages#4)-(Optional)(Android-only)-Listen-for-FCM-messages-in-the-background). Please note that this would work only on **android**.

Way 2 - **Notification + Data**

Send a notification and when user presses it, update the data of the application. This should work both for android and iOS. You can send key/value pairs in your notification and send a type as one of the key/value pairs. Now, when you handle the notification based on this type you can can API's and update data as required. You can read more about it [here](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/notifications/receiving-notifications)